# What is &= and |=

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operators

I was going through some VC++ code in a large code-base and came across this:

```
    if (nState & TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE)
        nState &= ~TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE;
    else
        nState |= TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE;
    break;
```

Is there any such operator as &= or |= in C++? What is it for?
Is it the equivalent of `nState = nState & ~TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE`?

Comment: The answer might not be as straight-forward as this (although it's highly likely that it is). I added some more info which you might find useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`x &= y`  is the same as  `x = x & y`
`x |= y`  is the same as  `x = x | y`

Comment: Not necessarily true, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

What hasn't been mentioned is that both `&=` and `|=` operators can be overloaded. Therefore, the code you posted depends on the type of nState (although it's quite clearly an int, so most probably this doesn't apply here). Overloading `&=` does not implicitly overload `&`, so in this case

```
x &= y might not be the same as x = x & y
```

It might also depend on what `TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE` is.

```
struct s{
   int x;
};

void operator &= (int& x, s y)
{
   x = 0;
}
```

Now whenever you do:

```
s TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE;
x &= TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE;
```

`x` will become `0`. Again, highly unlikely, but good to know nevertheless.

All other answer probably apply here, but this is worth considering.

Comment: You bring up a worthy concern, but if I found a code base which overloaded `&=` with one meaning and `&` with another, I would immediately fix such blatant non-orthogonality, and maybe look for someone to chastise, though they probably would be long gone for a legacy of such awfulness.  Overloading should be intuitive, enhancing code readability, not placing landmines all over.

Comment: Another case is that if `x` is an expression with side effects, `x |= y` will invoke that side effect once, while `x = x | y` will apply it twice (or even invoke undefined behaviour, if the side effects are not properly protected by sequence points). This is especially relevant for macros (although in C++ you should generally avoid those anyway).

Answer (score 3):

Its bitwise and or

in the first case the flag (bit) is turned off

```
nState &= ~TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE
```

in the second case the flag is turned on

```
nState |= TOOL_TIPS_VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 2):

`x &= y` means `x = x & y`. So yes you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `&=` is to `&` what `+=` is to `+`

Answer (score 1):

```
x &= y;
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = x & y;
```

In the same way,

```
x|= y;
```

is equivalent to:

```
x = x | y;
```

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `|` are similar to `&&` and `||`, only they works in bitwise fashion. So now you could imagine `&=` and `|=` works similar to `+=`. That is `x &= y; ==> x = x & y;`